# Mathematical Olympiad Treasures Problem 1.11

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $n$ be a positive integer, prove that:

$3^{3^{n}}(3^{3^{n}}+1) + 3^{3^{n} + 1} - 1$

is not prime

The solution states:

Observe:

$3^{3^{n}}(3^{3^{n}}+1) + 3^{3^{n} + 1} - 1 = a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3} - 3abc$

for $a = 3^{3^{n-1}}$, $b = 9^{3^{n-1}}$, $c = -1$

After that main insight the solution follows quite simply.

How are you supposed to find what $a$ and $b$ are. It makes sense to guess that $c = -1$ but finding $a$ and $b$ seems much harder, how do you guess it?

Comment: Isn't this number always even? An even number is not prime.

Comment: Yes it seems rather simple to show that the number is always even, or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I should add the chapter is on using 3rd degree algebraic identities. Out of curiosity how do you show it is even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3^{3^{n}}(3^{3^{n}}+1) + 3^{3^{n} + 1} - 1=\\
3^{2\cdot3^n}+3^{3^n}-1+3^{3^n+1}=\\
9^{3^n}+3^{3^n}-1+3^{3^n+1}\\
(9^{3^{n-1}})^3+(3^{3^{n-1}})^3+(-1)^3-3(9^{3^{n-1}}\cdot 3^{3^{n-1}}\cdot(-1))$$

Answer (score 4):

$$3^{3^{n}}(3^{3^{n}}+1) + 3^{3^{n} + 1} - 1\equiv 1\cdot 0 +1-1\equiv 0\bmod 2$$ hence it's not a prime